# Display only specific data from array containing database values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a query which select the last entered data into the database month wise and i have assigned it into an array and tried to display it inside a table which works fine but the data is combined togeather as shown below

[image: Table]

Example - the first numeric data you see on the table 1245871 should be displayed as follows

Month - 12
Closing Mileage - 45871

But as you can see on the image both the data are combined togeather how can i seperate these two values and display them accordingingly. The code for this is as below,

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$querymain = "SELECT * FROM users";
$resultsmain = mysqli_query($connect,$querymain);
if ($resultsmain->num_rows>0) {
    while ($userid = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultsmain)) {
        ?>
        <table class="table" class="mt-3 mb-3">
        <thead class="bg-dark text-light">
        <tr>
        <th colspan="3"><?php echo $userid['id']; ?></th>
        <th colspan="3"><?php echo $userid['name']; ?></th>
        <th colspan="3"><?php echo $userid['approved_kmpl'];?> KM</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Closing Mileage</th>
        <th>Usage For Month</th>
        <th>Required Per Month</th>
        <th>Excess Used</th>
        <th>(%)</th>
        <th>KM/L</th>
        <th>Consumed Liters</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
        
<?php         
    $closingmileage = "SELECT extract(MONTH from date) as Month,
                              MAX(mileage) FROM mileagesnew 
                        WHERE user_id='".$userid['id']."' 
                        AND extract(YEAR FROM date) ='2020' 
                        group by Month 
                        ORDER BY month desc";
        
    $closingres = mysqli_query($connect,$closingmileage);
     if ($closingres->num_rows>0) {
        while ($closingrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($closingres)) {
                
            $data =array($closingrow);
            foreach($data as $value){
                print_r($value);
                ?>
                <tr>
                <td> <?php echo implode($value); ?> </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                <td> <?php echo implode($value); ?> </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "No Data Found";
    }
    ?>
        
        </tbody>
        
        </table>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: do MOD for one and DIVIDE for another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 columns returned in the resultset of the query `Month` and `mileagesnew`. So `$closingrow` will be an array with 2 members, named as the columns names from your table, or the alias you give the column name in the query. So all you need to do is output `$closingrow['Month']` and `$closingrow['mileagesnew']` seperately in the 2 table cells

Also I assume you want the 2 values on the same row of the tabel to output both cells within the same `<tr>...</tr>` along with the empty cells you have not filled yet

```
<?php         
    $closingmileage = "SELECT extract(MONTH from date) as Month,
                              MAX(mileage) FROM mileagesnew 
                        WHERE user_id='".$userid['id']."' 
                        AND extract(YEAR FROM date) ='2020' 
                        group by Month 
                        ORDER BY month desc";
    
    $closingres = mysqli_query($connect,$closingmileage);
    if ($closingres->num_rows>0) {        
        while ($closingrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($closingres)) {
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>$closingrow[Month]}</td>
                    <td>$closingrow[mileagesnew ]</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>";
    
        }
    } else{
        echo "No Data Found";
    }
?>
```